# How to set the identifier for NSTableColumn in xcode 4 with interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

for the life of me i cannot find the field to enter the identifier for NSTableColumn in xcode4, in xcode3 it appeared simple, the field was directly below `title` in the attributes inspector, however i cannot find the appropriate field in ANY of the `inspectors` in xcode4.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean this?

[image: User Interface Item identifier]